# Is it possible to get information about a WhatsApp bot?

Tags: api, debugging, bots, chatbot, whatsapp

As I understand, every WhatsApp chatbot interacts with users through WhatsApp but the actual backend is hosted in a server of its own.

I was wondering if there is any way to get information about this server or its API when interacting with the chatbot. I tried fiddling on WhatsApp web with the developer console, with the network tab, but it appears that WhatsApp does a really good job masking the core of the bots.

Has anyone had any luck getting information about WhatsApp chatbots?

Answer (score 0):

Well from the question it's kinda already answered Meta uses just the response from the server from where the bot script is hosted after sending a webhook event to it so what you might be getting is gonna be info on the WhatsApp network... with the new Cloud API for WhatsApp business you could get more info on how the WhatsApp bot work
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).